# Cython cimport cannot find .pxd module

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

Assume a package is structured as:

```
Some_Package/ 
    some_package/
        __init__.py
        core/
            __init__.py
            definition.pxd
        helper/
            __init__.py
            helper.pxd
            helper.pyx
    setup.py
```

Where in `definition.pxd` I have:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
# ...
ctypedef np.int32_t INT_t
```

And in `helper.pxd` I have:

```
cimport some_package.core.definition
from some_package.core.definition cimport INT_t
# ...
```

In `helper.pyx` I didn't `cimport` anything. I configured `setup.py` as:

```
ext_modules=cythonize('./some_package/helper/helper.pyx', include_dirs=['.', './some_package/core'])
```

Now my problem is with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I can build successfully into `.so`, but when I tried to `import some_package.helper.helper` I got an `ImportError`:

`ImportError: No module named "some_package.helper.helper"`

I have looked into `helper.cpp` and found some lines like:

```
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_ImportModule("some_package.core.definition"); if (!__pyx_t_1) __PYX_ERR(0, 1, __pyx_L1_error)
```

I guess this might have something to do with import path, but I cannot spot what was wrong. All `__init__.py`'s are empty and I have imported `absolute_import` in every file. I also changed the `include_dirs`, but still not working.

**Edit #1**

According to the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#search-paths-for-definition-files), `include_dirs` adds to the `*.pxd` search path. So I also tried to change the `cimport` statements in `helper.pxd` as:

```
cimport definition
from definition cimport INT_t
```

This time, `cython` cannot compile: `"definition.pxd" not found`. However, it should be in the search path.

**Edit #2**

A quick workout is adding an empty `definition.pyx` in `core/`, then configure extensions as:

```
extensions = [
    Extension("some_package.core.definition", ["some_package/core/definition.pyx"])
    Extension("some_package.helper.helper", ["some_package/helper/helper.pyx"])
]
```

Then in `setup.py`:

```
ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
```

Now `cimport some_package.core.definition` is working in `helper.pxd`.

However, this is not elegant.

Comment: Wait, you called your package `src`? I would recommend using a different name first because that just screams for naming conflicts.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks! `src` is for illustration purposes (since I found it quite common). Indeed, `src` is named as `some_package` and is put in a root directory named `Some_Package`.

Comment: Yes, it's a directory for `src` files. In the end you take the code from there but build it as extension within your actual package. It's a bit confusing if the concepts are changed. :-]

Comment: @MSeifert Ok, I've fixed them. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overlook that I had some lines as:

```
cdef INT_t some_int = 1
```

However, in the `.pxd` file, there cannot be any *executable* code. In this case, it seems `Cython` treats it as a package, which is not as there is `.pyx` file.

There might be two methods to work around:

1. `cdef extern` from a `C` header.
2. Wrap-up to inline functions.

Comment: One has to use `include_path` in cythonize instead of `include_dirs` https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1480